# Getting error while creating View in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi Could any one please help me while creating a view in SQL server toad I'm getting below error.Thanks in Advanced.

```
USE [database];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GCRM_CONTRACT_ENTITLEMENT] ("objid","CONTRACT__TITLE")
AS

(with mycte as (
 SELECT  table1.Column1 as objid, 
 table1.Column2 CONTRACT__TITLE

      FROM table1       
      WHERE
      (
      (table1.struct_type = 0)                
      )     

)

SELECT  Stuff(( SELECT ',' + cast(CONTRACT__TITLE as varchar(2000)) 
           FROM mycte t2
          WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid]             
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')  AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT]
  FROM mycte t1
GROUP BY t1.[objid]
);
GO
```

Error:- SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

Comment: `View` does not accept parameters

Comment: Can you show me which line I'm unable to fig it out.Thanks

Comment: First line `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[GCRM_CONTRACT_ENTITLEMENT] ("objid","CONTRACT__TITLE")` in a view this is not allowed `("objid","CONTRACT__TITLE")`

Comment: I have created a view with parameters but first time I'm creating with "cte".so parameter not seems to b a problm.

Comment: If it is SQL Server  , why is it tagged as Oracle?

Comment: AFAIK syntax for SQL Server is `;WITH cte as (SELECT ... )`

Comment: Now I'm able to create a view but in that view I have just one coulmn "AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT" i also want one more coulmn "INCIDENT__ID" so i kept but getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CTE must be the first part of the batch, docs are [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx).

Change the body of your view to something like this:

```
WITH mycte(objid,
           CONTRACT__TITLE)
     AS (
     SELECT table1.Column1 AS objid,
            table1.Column2 AS CONTRACT__TITLE
     FROM table1
     WHERE table1.struct_type = 0)
     SELECT STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT ','+CAST(CONTRACT__TITLE AS VARCHAR(2000))
                     FROM mycte t2
                     WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT]
     FROM mycte t1
     GROUP BY t1.[objid];
```

**EDIT:**
*with added INCIDENT__ID*

```
WITH mycte(objid,
           CONTRACT__TITLE,
           INCIDENT__ID)
     AS (
     SELECT TABLE1.COLUMN1 AS objid,
            TABLE1.COLUMN2 AS CONTRACT__TITLE,
            TABLE2.COLUMN1 AS INCIDENT__ID
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE TABLE1.struct_type = 0)
     SELECT STUFF(
                 (
                     SELECT ','+CAST(CONTRACT__TITLE AS VARCHAR(2000))
                     FROM mycte t2
                     WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                 ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT],
            [INCIDENT__ID]
     FROM mycte t1
     GROUP BY t1.[objid],
              t1.[INCIDENT__ID];
```

Comment: Thanks thats really worked but i want one more coulmns in that view as i have only one right now "AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT" so when i tried to add more coulms getting error like SQL Server Database Error: Column 'mycte.INCIDENT__ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: If you are adding another column in the select that isn't aggregated e.g. not one of  `max`, `min`, `count` etc then you will also need to add the column name to your `group by`.  If you are aggregating inside your cte you will need to add a reference to 'mycte.INCIDENT__ID' in declaring the cte then  add a `group by` in there.

Comment: Can you please modify above query and  iam getting following error Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Create View or Function failed because no column name was specified for column 1.    

SELECT  min(INCIDENT__ID),Stuff(( SELECT ',' + cast(CONTRACT__TITLE as varchar(2000))
           FROM mycte t2
          WHERE t2.[objid] = t1.[objid]    and   t2.[INCIDENT__ID] = t1.[INCIDENT__ID]       
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')  AS [AVILABLE_ENTITLEMENT]
  FROM mycte t1
GROUP BY t1.[objid],t1.[INCIDENT__ID]